# SED Find&Replace with "OR"

Tags: linux, centos, command-line-interface, scripting, shell

After a bit of googling / research on my own i haven't found a definitive answer,

I'm looking to search the entire /var/www/html/ folder for occurances of "127.0.0.1" and replace them with a server IP address (we're moving the database off of the local box).

This goes for Localhost & 127.0.0.1.   While i could just run

```
find * | xargs sed -i a/127.0.0.1/ser.ver.ip.addr/g
```

twice, once replacing 127.0.0.1 and localhost, i'd rather not have to run two commands.

Am i able to do a OR statement without it breaking?

Something like:

```
find * | xargs sed -i a/127.0.0.1|localhost/ser.ver.ip.addr/g
```

----------------------------edit----------------------

I found a slightly more reliable method of doing a search & replace,

```
find * -type f -exec sed -i 's/127.0.0.1/ser.ver.ip.addr/g' {} \;
```

However i can't seem to get the search statement to match 127.0.0.1 **OR** localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -print | xargs sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/207.200.19.177/g' -e 's/localhost/207.200.19.177/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have to put it in quotes:

```
find * | xargs sed -i "a/127.0.0.1|localhost/ser.ver.ip.addr/g"
```

Comment: and of course: find . -type f

Comment: with or without quotes / ticks it seemed to work.